# Can I use the current release of Unitils (3.1) with JPA 2.0?

Tags: unit-testing, hibernate, jpa

Using Hibernate EntityManager **3.5.3-Final** together with Unitils 3.1 results in:

```
unitilsAfterTestTearDown(com.unifiedpost.payments.model.TestAccount)  Time elapsed: 0.02 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:621)
        at org.unitils.orm.jpa.util.provider.hibernate.UnitilsHibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(UnitilsHibernatePersistenceProvider.java:47)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:227)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:281)
        at org.unitils.orm.jpa.util.JpaEntityManagerFactoryLoader.createEntityManagerFactoryBean(JpaEntityManagerFactoryLoader.java:77)
```

This is also reported in:  http://jira.unitils.org/browse/UNI-201

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that unitils-orm depends on a 2.5.x release of Spring, which is not JPA2 ready yet.

```
[INFO] +- org.unitils:unitils-testng:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] +- org.unitils:unitils-orm:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.unitils:unitils-spring:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:2.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:2.5.2:test
```

See also:

- http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6408
- http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6705

You have 2 workaround options:

**(1) Patch Unitils:**

- Checkout Unitils (http://www.unitils.org/source-repository.html)
- Fix the root pom: Make it depend on a 3.0.1.RELEASE (or higher)
- Build a release locally
- Use this as your new Unitils package

> ```
> <properties>
>     <spring.version>3.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
>     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
> </properties>
> ```

**(2) Include a patched MutablePersistenceUnitInfo**

- Duplicate Spring MutablePersistenceUnitInfo in your project (and make sure it preceeds the legacy Spring version in the classpath)
- Add the missing methods to it.

> ```
> @Override
> public String getPersistenceXMLSchemaVersion() {
>     return "1.0";
> }
>
> @Override
> public SharedCacheMode getSharedCacheMode() {
>     return SharedCacheMode.NONE;
> }
>
> @Override
> public ValidationMode getValidationMode() {
>     return ValidationMode.NONE;
> }
> ```

*[Answered myself for later reference]*

Answer (score 0):

Also not a direct answer to the original question, but the trunk version (4.0-SNAPSHOT) has a Spring 3.0 dependency. Under the hood the JPA support will be re-engineered to use Spring ([1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unitils/forums/forum/570578/topic/3941983)).